# how to toggle between two css classes with react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to toggle between two classes dark mode and normal mode.

> **THis is the vanilla js eventlistener**

```
     const modeSwitch = document.querySelector('.mode-switch');

  modeSwitch.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.documentElement.classList.toggle('dark');
    modeSwitch.classList.toggle('active');
  });
```

> **This is the button that when clicked on, switches between the two modes. how can I achieve this with react**

```
     const [active, setActive] = useState(false)

     const handleToggle = () => {
      setActive(!active)
     }

 return (
    <button className="mode-switch" title="Switch Theme" onClick={handleToggle}>
          <svg className="moon" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <defs></defs>
            <path d="M21 12.79A9 9 0 1111.21 3 7 7 0 0021 12.79z"></path>
          </svg>
        </button>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could use `useRef`:

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(false)
const modeRef = useRef();

const handleToggle = () => {
     modeRef.current.classList.toggle("dark")
}

return (
    <button ref={modeRef} className="mode-switch" title="Switch Theme" onClick={handleToggle}>
          <svg className="moon" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <defs></defs>
            <path d="M21 12.79A9 9 0 1111.21 3 7 7 0 0021 12.79z"></path>
          </svg>
    </button>
)
```